# IIS6 SMTP service is the only available option in Win 2008r2.  Will it be depreciated, what are the options?

Tags: smtp, iis-6, deprecated, windows-server-2008-r2, exchange-server

I'm using the IIS6 SMTP service to handle inbound SMTP email, like this:

- [Writing Managed Sinks for SMTP and Transport Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998610)
- [smtpreg.vbs Event Management Script](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms528023.aspx)

What is the correct way of doing the same thing in Windows 2008R2 and onward?  I notice that Exchange 2010 doesn't use this SMTP server anymore so I think it may be depreciated...

Answer (score 0):

Windows Server 2008 R2 has the ability to add an SMTP server.  It's essentially the same one that came in 2003.  You add it via the Add Features wizard from within Server Manager.  Here's the link to the tecnhet article describing the process.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772058(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: Once I add the mail server, (I've already done that) how to I hook the IIS internal events without using VS2005 to create the DLL?